# What is the cost of increased neural adaption for strenght?

Tags: human-physiology

Axiom: Physical strength is a function of muscle mass and neural adaption.

I understand that increases in muscle mass incur associated metabolic costs. What are the corresponding costs for neural adaption for strength?

Comment: not just muscle mass, muscle composition as well, chimp muscles are stronger (~1.4 times) than our at the cost of worse endurance, because they have more fast twitch fibers. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5514706/